# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVAudioInputNode'

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioengine

What causes the error stated above and how to fix it ?

```
func cancelRecording() {
        audioEngine.stop()
        if let node = audioEngine.inputNode {
            node.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        }
        recognitionTask?.cancel()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you can't use an if let because it's totally unnecessary. You don't have any optionals to unwrap: **audioEngine** is not optional, and the **inputNode** property isn't optional either. if let is used exclusively to unwrap optionals. If you want to create a new constant named  **node**, just do it:

```
if let node = audioEngine?.inputNode {
   node.removeTap(onBus: 0)
}
```

Comment: Sir , i would like to ask you something about alexa voices services

Comment: @JhonDonCaylog yes please tell what you want with alexa voice services?

Comment: Have you tried integrading alexa voices services to an ios app ?

Comment: not yet but you can tell me the problem what you are facing?

Comment: i wanted to integrate alexa voices services using api.ai into an Ios App Sir.

Comment: when i ask something to alexa he will reply data from api.api

Comment: i am currently implementing this repo https://github.com/eironeia/alexa-simulator-iOS

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: i dont know how to integrate it from api.ai , and also i have problem in what i want which is i wanted to say something and alexa will repeat it

Comment: Find API+ViewController.swift it is sending text to server api.ai

Comment: i have found it Sir, now what details that i am going to provide

Comment: you should send the parameters, query is the array of text, language is "en" & sessionId keep it is same n try

Comment: is the array of text dynamic ? or is just ""Show me the latest price of Apple"?

Comment: it is array of text dynamic

Comment: i am using api v2